# How to update attribute of polygon shapefile by iterating through each csv file?

Tags: python, model, gis, automatic-ref-counting

I have multiple csv files with many columns. I would like to join the attribute of a shapefile with each csv file columns and want to export them as shapefiles related to each csv file.

I am expecting generating multiple shapefiles with different attributes related by iterating through each csv file.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way you can do that, using [`merge()`](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/user_guide/mergingdata.html#attribute-joins) method of GeoPandas:

Shapefile `points.shp`:

```
id       City                          geometry
-----------------------------------------------
1    New York  POINT (-8253746.144 4957698.430)
2      Boston  POINT (-7908532.427 5205459.471)
3  Washington  POINT (-8575835.498 4706633.908)
4     Chicago  POINT (-9768391.975 5135260.509)
```

CSV `cities.csv`:

```
      City          State
-------------------------
  New York       New York
    Boston  Massachusetts
Washington            ---
   Chicago       Illinois
```

```
import geopandas as gpd
import pandas as pd

SHP_PATH = r"C:\Temp\points.shp"
CSV_PATH = r"C:\Temp\cities.csv"

shp_df = gpd.read_file(SHP_PATH)
csv_df = pd.read_csv(CSV_PATH)

result = shp_df.merge(csv_df, on="City")

result.to_file(r"C:\Temp\result.shp")
```

Result:

```
  id        City                          geometry          State
------------------------------------------------------------------
   1    New York  POINT (-8253746.144 4957698.430)       New York
   2      Boston  POINT (-7908532.427 5205459.471)  Massachusetts
   3  Washington  POINT (-8575835.498 4706633.908)            ---
   4     Chicago  POINT (-9768391.975 5135260.509)       Illinois
```

Comment: Thank you, @isshp for taking the time to provide your suggestions but how to apply the same process on multiple CSV files by keeping the same shapefile?

Comment: Just iteatre through a list of CSV files and merge each one of them the updated GeoDataFrame using the same logic.